# Contiki process halts

Tags: c, contiki, cooja

i am trying to write a small process thread that will listen incoming data, write it to flash and read it afterwards.
The code looks like this

```
PROCESS(test_serial, "serial");
PROCESS(read_file, "readfile");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&test_serial);

PROCESS_THREAD(read_file, ev, data)
{
  PROCESS_BEGIN();
  int r = 0;

  if(cfs_seek(fd, 0, CFS_SEEK_SET) != 0) {
    printf("seek failed\n");
    cfs_close(fd);
  }

  while (total_bytes_written > 0)
  {
    uint8_t testbuff[10] = {0};
    r = cfs_read(fd, testbuff, 10);
    if(r != 10) {
      LOG_ERR("failed to read %d bytes, read only %d",total_bytes_written, r);
      cfs_close(fd);
      total_bytes_written = r;
    }
    total_bytes_written -= r;
  }
  total_bytes_written = 0;
  cfs_close(fd);
  PROCESS_END();
}

PROCESS_THREAD(test_serial, ev, data)
{
  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  while(1) {
    PROCESS_YIELD();
    if(ev == serial_line_event_message) {
      switch (*(uint8_t *)data)
      {
      case BEGINN:
        open_file();
        write_to_flash((uint8_t *)(data + 1));
        break;
      case CONTINUE:
        write_to_flash((uint8_t *)(data + 1));
        break;
      case END:
        write_to_flash((uint8_t *)(data + 1));
        process_start(&read_file, NULL);
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  PROCESS_END();
}
```

Writing to the flash works and I therefore did not include the code. This code is pretty much like the example in the [contiki documentation](https://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/Contiki_Coffee_File_System).

*total_bytes_written* will be incremented every time I write to the flash. After I received all the bytes, I try to read them. The problem is, that the process seems to be stoped when **process.c** calls **do_poll** for the *event timer* and does not resume afterwards.
In my understanding, AUTOSTART_PROCESSES adds my process to the list of processes for Contiki. Therefore Contiki should resume my process after *event timer* poll, since there is nothing to do for the event and I dont have any other processes running?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems the process did not halt. The problem is that once another event occurred, the logging got stoped.
When i made a small script that triggered a logging on an event, it had enough time until the next event to log everything.
The only mistery right now is how to apply logging without interruption.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).